# Terminate stream when Maybe is empty without throwing the exception

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have the following method that is called reactively via REST:

```
public Single<Result> generateValue(Request request) {
    return valueService.create(request.getArg())
        .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromAction(() -> new Result(new JsonObject()))) //empty result
        .toSingle()
        .flatMap(value -> repositoryService.persist(value))
        .map(obj -> new Result(obj.toJson()));
    }
```

I can terminate the stream with `Maybe.error(new Exception())` but the calling side will get the error response that I don't want to send.

Is it possible to return `Single<Result>` (terminate the stream in the middle) when external service returns `Maybe.empty()`, without resuming  the main stream (from `toSingle()` line)?

**Update**

I tried to put `flatMap` + `map` block before `switchIfEmpty` as @akarnokd suggested. First of all I extracted them to the separate method:

```
private Single<Result> persistValue(Value value) {
        return repositoryService.persist(value))
                 .map(obj -> new Result(obj.toJson()));
    }
```

And use this method in the main pipeline:

```
public Single<Result> generateValue(Request request) {
    return valueService.create(request.getArg())
        .map(this::persistValue)
        .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromAction(() -> new Result(new JsonObject()))) //empty result
        .toSingle()
        .cast(Result.class);
    }
```

This time, when `Maybe.empty()` is returned, I get:

`Operation could not be performed as entity stream did not return any results: The MaybeSource is empty`

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: The MaybeSource is empty`

because its empty state is passed to `persistValue` method. Perhaps I didn't catch the main idea of putting `map` after `Maybe.empty()` before `switchIfEmpty`.

**Update 2**

Mock class to copy and run the scenario. `JsonObject` is from gson lib.

```
public class MockExample {

    @Test
    public void testGenerateValue() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.generateValue(new Request("testVal"))
                .subscribe();
    }

    class Handler {
        MockValueService valueService = new MockValueService();
        MockRepositoryService repositoryService = new MockRepositoryService();

        public Single<Result> generateValue(Request request) {
            return valueService.create(request.getArg())
                    .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromAction(() -> new Result(new JsonObject()))) //empty result
                    .toSingle()
                    .flatMap(value -> repositoryService.persist(value))
                    .map(obj -> new Result(obj.toJson()));
        }
    }

    class MockValueService {
        public Maybe<Value> create(String arg) {
            return Maybe.empty();
        }
    }

    class MockRepositoryService {
        public Single<Value> persist(Value value) {
            return Single.just(value);
        }
    }

    class Result {
        private JsonElement json;

        public Result(JsonElement json) {
            this.json = json;
        }

        public JsonElement getJson() {
            return json;
        }
    }

    class Request {
        private String arg;

        public Request(String arg) {
            this.arg = arg;
        }

        public String getArg() {
            return arg;
        }
    }

    class Value {
        private JsonObject original;

        public Value(JsonObject original) {
            this.original = original;
        }

        public JsonObject toJson() {
            return original;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of object is `Result`? Does it have a representation for "no content"? If not, perhaps you should return something like an `Optional`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- no, it doesn't have representation for "no content" that's why `new JsonObject()` is passed there to return empty result. Unfortunately `repositoryService` is some sort of legacy lib and that method returns `Maybe`. Well, if there's no way to terminate stream but return Maybe.error() then ok, I'll think about some other approach to implement this method.

Comment: Why don't you put the `map` before the `switchIfEmpty`? If `create` is empty, `map` won't run but `switchIfEntry` will.

Comment: @akarnokd hm, I didn't think about such stream construction. Thanks. Btw, will it work if before `map` there'll be one more `flatMap` step?

Comment: @akarnokd I put `map` before `switchIfEmpty` and got `Operation could not be performed as entity stream did not return any results: The MaybeSource is empty`.

Comment: Where does that error come from? Could you provide a self-contained example (with mockup service calls) that demonstrates the problems you are facing?

Comment: @akarnokd I've updated topic.

Comment: Please post a self-contained unit tests demonstrating your problem. I still don't see where that error would come from. In addition, mapping via `map(this::persistValue)` is certainly the wrong thing to do as it just nests a `Single` inside a `Maybe` without running it.

Comment: @akarnokd added mock example of initial issue without swap of `map` and `switchIfEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the mock example, I can now see the issues:

1. `.switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromAction(() -> ...))` is empty because `Maybe.fromAction` never produces a success value. You mistook it for `fromCallable`.
2. `persist` returns `Single` which requires `flatMapSingle` to be merged into the sequence.
3. To ensure the types remain correct, you have to move the mappings before the `switchIfEmpty` call.

Try this setup:

```java
public Single<Result> generateValue(Request request) {
    return valueService.create(request.getArg())
            .flatMapSingleElement(value -> repositoryService.persist(value))
            .map(obj -> new Result(obj.toJson()))
            .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.fromCallable(() -> new Result(new JsonObject())))
            .toSingle()
            ;
}
```

Comment: Oh, `flatMapSingleElement` and 'Maybe.fromCallable` did the magic. Thanks a lot. I need to dive into details in these methods for sure.